# freeze the header of rpivotTable shiny

Tags: r, shiny, rpivottable

In shiny `rpivotTable` how can I freeze the header?

I know how to add a scroll bar in css to the pivot table, however I don't know how to freeze the header.

```
#PivotFinal {
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `postion:fixed` for header element?

Comment: I tried position fixed but it did not seem to work.

Comment: table.pvtTable thead tr th{
  background: blue;
  position: fixed;
}

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to do it, in the .css file I added the below code.

```
table.pvtTable thead th{
  position: sticky;
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 999;
}
```